# How to use existing web form based authentication and authorization in angularjs web api SPA?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, webforms

I am planning to add new functionalities using angularjs and web api over an existing asp.net webform site. Once finished, both the webforms and the angularjs will coexist. In all the sample applications of angularjs and web api, I see a login page being created and OAuth authentication is being used through the token service. Is there any way I could use the existing webform based authentication/authorization in the newly added angular/web api project? If you know any sample code please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at this example http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/05/26/AngularJS-Basic-HTTP-Authentication-Example.aspx using the `Basic` authentication header where in your Authentication service you'd make a call to your backend to perform the authentication and return a 'token' (hash/base64) in the response and assign it to the Authorization header.